# how to tokenize a paragraph in xslt

Tags: css, xml, xslt, xpath

**XML**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <!-- Edited by XMLSpy -->
   <catalog>
   <example>
   :20:FT13261793408907
   N23B:CRED
   SA32A:130918USD111670,00
   </example>
   </catalog>
```

**XSLT**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">


     <xsl:for-each select="catalog">
     <tr>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="example"> </td>
      </tr>
       </xsl:for-each>
     </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Current OUTPUT**

:20:FT13261793408907 N23B:CRED SA32A:130918USD111670,00

**Desired OUTPUT**

```
:20:FT13261793408907
N23B:CRED
SA32A:130918USD111670,00
```

output must not be in a same line its must be as shown in the desired o/p

Comment: Is your output HTML? If yes, then should the current and expected output _also_ as HTML, not as plain text.

Comment: Your XSLT makes no sense whatsoever: the output method is `text`, yet you try to write `<html>`,  `<body>`, etc. elements to the output. It's also not well-formed, so it cannot produce **any** output other than an error.  Please clarify what is your expected output format.

Comment: now I removed HTML tags Michael,my out must be in consecutive lines not in same line pls help

Comment: "*now I removed HTML tags*" No, you haven't: `<tr>` and `<td>` are still there. Take a look here: http://xsltransform.net/bdxtpK/1

Comment: Satheesh, the answer depends entirely on whether you need to output HTML or text. And you haven't clearly answered that question.

Comment: hi larsh I need the output as text

Comment: Your XSLT code, applied to your XML input _already_ outputs three lines of text - tested with Saxon 6.5, Saxon 9.5 and Xalan 2.7. Voting to close.

Comment: but I tried with www.w3schools.com/xsl/tryxslt.asp its showing in same line and I tried on thunder bird browser there also same problem

Comment: If you are viewing the results in a browser then you probably don't want to output just text as the browser may expect HTML and will just treat line breaks as insignificant whitespace. Your XSLT is outputting the line breaks, but it is just a case of how you are choosing to view the output that is the issue. If you do want the results shown in the browser, try changing the output method back to "html" and wrapping your `xsl:value-of` statement in a `pre` tag which will preserve formatting in HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A template match should do it;

```
$ cat catalog.xsl
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
        <xsl:output method="text"/>
        <xsl:template match="catalog">
                <xsl:value-of select="example"/>
        </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

$ xsltproc catalog.xsl catalog.xml

:20:FT13261793408907
N23B:CRED
SA32A:130918USD111670,00
```

Comment: hi I tried matching templete but if I change the template from / to book am not getting any output

Comment: If you match on book instead of catalog, than you should take the value of the current node, so <xsl:value-of select="."/>

Comment: @SatheeshKumar You have to provide complete information on your problem. Edit your post and include _all_ of your XSLT code (i.e. a complete stylesheet). Otherwise, answering is just guesswork.

Comment: hi @mathias pls help me I have provided the code and am trying all the possible ways but am not able to get the desired output

Comment: @SatheeshKumar: There's no `<book>` shown in your input XML. And the code you showed doesn't have anything about "book" (in the match pattern? in the value-of select?). You're really asking people to grope in the dark.

Comment: larsh pls check the edited code you are checking the old one I have modified the entire code this is an answer given for my old code